# Get client source IP on docker for Windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm, windows-server

I have a docker container running on a Windows Server host, it has a Java app running which communicates with remote client bidirectionally, when the remote client communicates with my server it gets the Docker gateway ip, 10.1.0.1 instead of the remote ip;

[image: Problem with local ip]

It only happens on Windows host, with an Ubuntu Server host it works without any trouble, I get the remote client ip, which I need to answer the petition.

Things I tried:

- Disable ip masquerading from docker-compose.yaml file with;

  ```
  com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade: 'false'
  ```
- Disable ip masquerading from daemon.json with;

  ```
  "ip-mask": false
  ```

This is how I create the network on docker-compose.yaml;

[image: docker-compose.yaml]

Nothing of these two solutions worked, thanks in advance.